# Puma doesn't installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm new in Ruby and Rails. I've already installed node=v12.18.2, nvm=0.32.1, yarn=1.22.4, rbenv=1.1.2, ruby=2.7.1, rails=6.0.3.2, sqlite3=3.28.0, openssl via homebrew.
I'm using mac.
When I'm trying to start new project with command

```
rails new .
```

I have this stacktrace:

```
...
Fetching puma 4.3.5
Installing puma 4.3.5 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/kir/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
/Users/kir/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/ruby -I /Users/kir/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200822-18390-17806vx.rb extconf.rb --with-opt-dir\=/usr/local/opt/openssl
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... yes
checking for openssl/bio.h... yes
checking for DTLS_method() in openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for TLS_server_method() in openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version in openssl/ssl.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/kir/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/kir/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR="
compiling http11_parser.c
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:44:18: warning: unused variable 'puma_parser_en_main' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int puma_parser_en_main = 1;
                 ^
1 warning generated.
compiling io_buffer.c
compiling mini_ssl.c
mini_ssl.c:145:7: warning: unused variable 'min' [-Wunused-variable]
  int min, ssl_options;
      ^
mini_ssl.c:299:40: warning: function 'raise_error' could be declared with attribute 'noreturn' [-Wmissing-noreturn]
void raise_error(SSL* ssl, int result) {
                                       ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling puma_http11.c
puma_http11.c:203:22: error: implicitly declaring library function 'isspace' with type 'int (int)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  while (vlen > 0 && isspace(value[vlen - 1])) vlen--;
                     ^
puma_http11.c:203:22: note: include the header <ctype.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'isspace'
1 error generated.
make: *** [puma_http11.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/kir/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/kir/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.7.0/puma-4.3.5/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing puma (4.3.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '4.3.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  puma
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
bundler: command not found: spring
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
       rails  webpacker:install
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

What's wrong and what should I do?

Comment: Try to read this thread and the proposed workarounds https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/2304#issuecomment-666347735

Comment: @hernanvicente , thank you! I did
`bundle config build.puma --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"`

Then `bundle install`, and it continuous

Comment: Can you use other patch versions of 4.3? It seems this is solved in Puma 5, but it is still in beta.